# Java Dynamic Web Project Spring MVC can't implement function from .js file

Tags: jquery

I use Java spring MVC framework and I want to implement a jQuery script function to hide 'p' bracket when I click a button.

A variant to the file my-query-page.jsp and jq_functions.js can be seen below

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").hide();
    });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>this is me learning jQuery</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>   
    
    <!--     THIS DOESN'T WORK        -->
    <script src="/resources/js/jq_functions.js"></script>
    
</head>
<body>
<h2> this is me learning jQuery</h2>
<p>this is a line of text</p>
<p>this is a second line of text</p>
<p>this is a third line of text</p>
 <button>Hide</button>
</body>
</html>
```

the page load properly and no error on the console

so I click the button and the 'p' text does not hide

how can I make the button hide the 'p' text?

So when it's not a reference to an external file .js and when the query is inside the .jsp file it works fine, but I don't know how to make it happen with an external file.

Here's a view to my file system

[image: File stack view]

Any idea how to make this work?

Comment: Check in the generated html if the url of the js file point to the js file properly. <script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jq_functions.js" />"></script> rest looks fine !

Comment: Any error in your browser console ?

Comment: Yours works here. Maybe you indicated the wrong path to the js file?

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of your browser's developer tools?

Comment: @connexo I get this error Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 ()

Comment: So the path is not correct, and your JS is never executed. Have your tried `<script src="./view/resources/js/jq_functions.js"></script>`?

Comment: So I red online that since my file is .jsp it is executed server-side but sciptlets are executed client-side. Does that make sense for anyone?